# UITextView attributed text issue with HTML tag Videos and tables

Tags: ios, objective-c

`UITextView` in iOS 7. I used attributed text to support HTML tags.
But it crashes, when I tried to embed Videos (using iFrame) and the HTML tables are also not supported.

Comment: UITextView is not done for that. You should use `UIWebView`.

Comment: I have more than one field which may or may not(plain text) html tags embedded in it.And it needs to be resizable depending on each contents.So went with textView.

Comment: Put the views programatically rather than statically in Interface Builder then. You can change the type of view to UITextView or UIWebView as per your need.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try.Does textView have some thing like supported tags?